# different behavior es6 Proxy on NodeJs and Web when return in class constructor that extends

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, parse-server, es6-proxy

```js
import * as Parse from 'parse';
import { Object as ParseObject } from 'parse';
export interface IItem {
  num: number;
}
export class Item extends ParseObject<IItem> implements IItem {
 num = 1;
  constructor(attributes?: IItem) {
    super('Item', attributes!);
    return new Proxy<Item>(this, /*this handles may empty {} but keep this way for verbosity*/{
      set: (a, b, c, d): boolean => {
        return Reflect.set(a, b, c, d);
      },
      construct: (a, b, c): any => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
        return Reflect.construct(a as unknown as Function, b, c);
      },
      get: (a, b, c): any => {
        return Reflect.get(a, b, c);
      },
      apply: (a, b, c): any => {
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-types
        return Reflect.apply(a as unknown as Function, b, c);
      },
      defineProperty: (a, b, c): any => {
        return Reflect.defineProperty(a, b, c);
      },
      getPrototypeOf: (t): any => {
        return Reflect.getPrototypeOf(t);
      },
      deleteProperty: (a, b): any => {
        return Reflect.deleteProperty(a, b);
      },
      has: (a, b): any => {
        return Reflect.has(a, b);
      },
      ownKeys: (t): any => {
        return Reflect.ownKeys(t);
      },
      getOwnPropertyDescriptor: (a, b): any => {
        return Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(a, b);
      },
      isExtensible: (t): any => {
        return Reflect.isExtensible(t);
      },
      preventExtensions: (t): any => {
        return Reflect.preventExtensions(t);
      },
      setPrototypeOf: (a, b): any => {
        return Reflect.setPrototypeOf(a, b);
      },
    });
  }

}
const ite /*Proxy of Item*/ = new Item({ num: 980 });
console.log('get num', ite.get('num')); // should return `980`
```

The code describes the usage of a proxy in a constructor.

Getter and Setters work as spected but the inherited properties from `extends ParseObject` do not.

The get function retrieves objects from the ParseObject.attributes https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#parseobject so is the same as `ParseObject.attributes.num` === `ParseObject.get('num')`

I implemented this patter to get a js Class to behave as a parse object without calling the `ParseObject.set('prop')`. On web browsers, raw or transpiled in angular works as spected.

```js
ite.get('num') // returns `980`
ite.attributes // returns `{ num: 980 }`
```

But in NodeJs, transpiled from typescript and raw typescript, bundled with webpack, rollup.

```js
ite.get('num') // returns `undefined`
ite.attributes // returns `{}`
```

I don't get the mistake. If someone can explain why this happens to figure a workarround in NodeJs for this proxy constructor approach that works on web but not on node

Comment: The [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse) says "*the Parse npm module contains special versions of the SDK tailored to use in Node.js*" - any chance you're actually running a different library code?

Comment: Does this also happen if you don't return a proxy?

Comment: Using a `new Proxy(this)` instead of `this` messes up object references, such as when the instance is stored in a `Map` or `WeakMap`. Does your (browser) build include any polyfills for these?

Comment: @Bergi yes, I've used both versions, no, It works fine when not returning a proxy, but the way it is is pretty usefull when making changes in a frontend app. I

Comment: I've tried it on angular build, and raw js, and worked the same. Yeah, thats why I'm using proxy, to mess the call and get transformations and send it to the ParseObject.api. I'm confused since It works right way on browser :(

Comment: I don't think you need a proxy to mess with anything. Just overwrite the respective methods of the `ParseObject` class. It doesn't seem well-documented, but the code is publicly avaiable.

Comment: I was thinking that, but is quite large and is just pure js :(

Comment: Well it seems you need to do some debugging of that code anyway if the proxy solution isn't working :P If you need help, you could ask a new question where you're more specific about what messing with calls and transformations you want to do.